# Accessing calendars on other devices using expo-calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-calendar

From the docs, I see that one is only able to access calendars on one's own device. Is it possible to access calendars located on a server, or another persons device, with which the user can view as a guest or editor?

So far I've tried setting the source to non local, but I don't know how to associate the non local calendar with a universal CalendarID.